# New to Linux, cannot get my internet to connect in VMWare

Tags: linux, networking, vmware, centos, centos-7

I installed CentOS today and did a minimal install.  I got everything set up and got Gnome installed but I simply cannot connect to the internet.  I can ping my loopback address and everything looks fine to me, but again I'm new.  Could someone take a look at this?

```
# ifconfig
eno16777736: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.206.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.206.255
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe81:3f69  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:0c:29:81:3f:69  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 228  bytes 25336 (24.7 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 130  bytes 13117 (12.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 10  bytes 620 (620.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 10  bytes 620 (620.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My resolv.conf:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain localdomain
search localdomain
nameserver 192.168.206.1
```

First time noticing that my sysconfig/network was blank... hmmm... bet this is my problem.  What should go here?

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Comment: in the vmware settings for the network adapter, is NAT selected?

Comment: Have you added your user to the vboxusers group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using VMWare, you can change the adapter settings for your virtual machine.
I am using VMWare fusion on the Mac, but it should be the same thing for the windows version:

You have 3 options for your network adapter settings :

- Bridged
- NAT
- Host-only

You can use both "Bridged" and "NAT" for internet access, the difference between both being mainly whether or not other machines on your network can interact with that virtual machine.

More info on the differences between "Bridged" and "NAT" can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/229860/vmware-networking-mode-nat-or-bridged).

With a clean installation of a virtual machine, having access to the internet should be as simple as changing your network adapter settings in your VMWare client. If this doesn't work, you will probably have to setup some configurations in your virtual machine.

Comment: No problem :) Have fun with your new machine!